# Is there a cleaner way to mock a class to return a new autospec instance?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm working on tests for code that interacts with a complex vendor library. In order to be sure the mocked entities from the library are correct, I'm using the following:

```
import vendor
import mypkg

_item_klass = vendor.lib.item
def _item(arg1, arg2):
    return mock.autospec(_item_klass, spec_set=True, prop1=arg1, prop2=arg2)

@patch.object(vendor.lib, "item", side_effect=_item)
def test_behavior(item_class_mock):
    mypkg.mod.my_api()
    item_class_mock.assert_called_with("expected", "values")
```

This works as desired.  What I dislike is the `_item_klass` global.  I use this instead of passing the literal `vendor.lib.item` because when `_item()` is invoked as the side-effect, `vendor.lib.item` is already mocked by the `patch.object()` call; the resulting mock is only an autospec of `Mock`.

I tried using `@patch("mypkg.mod.vendor.lib.item")` but in that case saw errors that *one of* the properties on the mock instance did not exist and so could not be set; not sure how to fix that.

Is there an alternate, cleaner way to refer back to the actual class for autospec'ing while that class is patched?